# Prototype inheritance - access props inside prototype property

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

```
a = function() {}
a.prototype.b = 10
console.log(a.b)
```

My understanding of prototype inheritance is, if the property is defined in the object itself, then that prop's value is defined.

If the property is not defined in the object, then it looks up the prototype chain, which i understand as a look-up under `a.prototype` and returns value.

In the above case, it prints `undefined` whereas i expect `10`.

Comment: `a.prototype` is not in the prototype chain of `a`. `a.prototype` is not the prototype of `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
console.log(new a().b);
```

`a` is the function (which is an object too) self, while the prototype chain is for the instances initialized by the constructor function `a`.

Another example:

```
a = function() {};
Function.prototype.b = 10;
console.log(a.b); // this time you will get 10
```

`a` is a function which is also an object, you add a property to `Function.prototype`, then prototype chain for `a` works.

Comment: Note that (as seen in my answer) `console.log(a.prototype.b);` also works. Also note that `Function.prototype` modifies the prototype of ALL future functions while `a.prototype` only modifies the prototype of `a`.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable "`console.log(a.prototype.b);` also works. " doesn't make sense for `a.prototype.b = 10`, it's obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = function() {};
```

`a` is a function

```
a.prototype.b = 10;
```

all instances of `a` start with the property value `.b` of 10.

```
console.log(a.b) //undefined
```

`a` is not an instance of a, and as a result it is only `function(){}` which has no property b and therefore logs undefined.

```
var A = new a();
console.log(A.b);//10;
```

Now we have an instance of a, and as a result 10 is logged.

Answer (score 1):

Only instances of classes/objects/functions inherit from their `prototype` property. To access properties in a function's prototype you can use functionName.prototype.propertyname. or you can create a new instance inline.

```
console.log(a.b);
```

Should be:

```
console.log(new a().b);
//OR
console.log(a.prototype.b);
```

More on [prototypes (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Comment: *"Prototypes are only applied to their parent function(/class)"* It's not really clear what that means.

Comment: @Felix Kling *"...when their parent is instantiated."*. Meaning that as long as you haven't assigned the result of the class or used the 'new' keyword the prototype isn't applied to the class itself

Comment: `prototype` is never "applied" to the function/class itself (not sure what "applying" a prototype means either). I'm sure you know how it works, but the description doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: with applied i ment that the class inherits from prototype. Too bad there isn't an RFC for the word 'applied' (there is for words like ['should'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype))...

Comment: But again, the function never inherits from its `prototype` property. Only instances created by that function do. Maybe you mean that...

Comment: Just made a tiny addition :)